Error parsing JSON: Invalid JSON primitive
My Azure YAML Pipeline is failing at Powershell step, not sure why but ConvertFrom-Json line is failing no matter what
Below is the appsettings.json file looks like:
{
  "TestExecution": {
    "TestEnvironment": "$(RUNENVIRONMENTGLOBALLY)",
    "DefaultWaitInSec": 30
  }
}

Below is the YAML I am using
variables:
  RUNENVIRONMENTGLOBALLY : PREPROD

 steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Set Environment To Run'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |        
        $appsettingsPath = '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\appsettings.json'
        $appsettingsContent = Get-Content -Path $appsettingsPath -Raw
        Write-Output $appsettingsContent

        try 
        {
            $appsettingsObject = ConvertFrom-Json $appsettingsContent
            Write-Output $appsettingsObject        
            $appsettingsObject.TestEnvironment = ${RUNENVIRONMENTGLOBALLY}
            $updatedAppsettings = ConvertTo-Json $appsettingsObject -Compress
            Set-Content -Path $appsettingsPath -Value $updatedAppsettings -Force
            Write-Output "Successfully updated appsettings.json"
        }
        catch
        {
              Write-Output "Error parsing JSON: $_"
        }


If there is another thing inside try {...} that throws an exception, your message still claims that it's an error with parsing JSON.

There is nothing extra inside try{...}
is there anything wrong with appsettings.json file ?? is variable declaration correct
"TestEnvironment": "$(RUNENVIRONMENTGLOBALLY)"

I saved the file to test.json, then ran $appsettingsContent = Get-Content -Path "./test.json" -Raw followed by $appsettingsObject = ConvertFrom-Json $appsettingsContent and didn't see any error. So I wonder if $appsettingsObject.TestEnvironment = ... caused an error.

I tried $appsettingsObject.TestEnvironment = "PREPROD" and it tells me Exception setting "TestEnvironment": "The property 'TestEnvironment' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.". Indeed there was no such key in the JSON object. Did you mean $appsettingsObject.TestExecution.TestEnvironment or something else?

You are spot on ...
Error parsing JSON: Exception setting "TestEnvironment": "The property 'TestEnvironment' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
This is exact error i see everytime.
I cant figure out which line it is failing !!!

So the problem is not with ConvertTo-Json but rather with $appsettingsObject.TestEnvironment = .... There is no problem with the json file itself. The string "Error parsing JSON: $_" can be misleading, as it's printed no matter what you actually catch.

This can be culprit            $appsettingsObject.TestEnvironment = ${RUNENVIRONMENTGLOBALLY}

Please note that the right syntax for referencing a pipeline variable is $(myvar) (macro syntax) or ${{ variables.myvar }} (template expression syntax).
Also, the json string has an extra property that is not being referenced (TestExecution)
Instead of:
$appsettingsObject.TestEnvironment = ${RUNENVIRONMENTGLOBALLY}

Try:
$appsettingsObject.TestExecution.TestEnvironment = "$(RUNENVIRONMENTGLOBALLY)"

